# Substring function in C

Tags: c, strings

I am trying to implement substring in C. How efficient and standard is this code? I have a hard time understanding how C functions are usually meant to work, like how `printf()` returns an `int` or `size_t`.

```
size_t substring(char *destination, char const *string,  int start, int len) {
    // writes a substring to the destinaton starting at start index of string until end stepping by step
    // follows the same start at 0 off by one on the end format as Java substring method
    int substringLength = len;

    int stringLength = strlen(string);

    if (start > stringLength || len > stringLength || start < 0 || len < 0) {
        fputs("start and len must be 0 < start/len < length of string", stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    if (start >= len) {
        fputs("start must be start < len", stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    memcpy(destination, &string[start], substringLength);

    if (destination[stringLength] != '\x0') {
        destination[stringLength] = '\x0';
    }
    return substringLength;
}
```

Comment: It would be good to note that you could just use the standard `memmove()` or `memcpy()` to accomplish this.

Comment: @syb0rg We are being asked to review this wrapper for `memcpy()`. What's your point?

Comment: @200_success I guess it was poorly communicated in my comment, but I in terms of efficiency *alone* I was thinking he could discard the wrapper and just use the standard functions alone.

Comment: @syb0rg There is significant benefit to using a wrapper instead of calling `memmove()` or `memcpy()` directly, since those functions don't handle NUL-termination.

Answer (score 3):

## Argument confusion

If you were trying to replicate the java substring function, you should have had a `start` and `end` argument.  As it is, you have a `start` and `length` argument, but you didn't handle the `length` argument correctly.

## Bug 1

This line doesn't correctly check for the case of copying off the end of the source string:

> ```
> if (start > stringLength || len > stringLength || start < 0 || len < 0) {
> ```

It needs to be:

```
if (start + len > stringLength || start < 0 || len < 0) {
```

Edit: If you want to check for integer overflow, you can also throw in `|| start + len < 0`, and use `size_t` everywhere instead of `int`.

## Bug 2

This check is unnecessary and can return an error incorrectly:

> ```
> if (start >= len) {
>     fputs("start must be start < len", stderr);
>     return -1;
> }
> ```

For example, if the string has 10 bytes, `start` is 8 and `len` is 1, this check will return an error.

## Bug 3

When you terminate the destination string, you use the wrong index.  It should be `len`, not `stringLength`.  Also, I'm not sure why you do a check before you write to it:

> ```
> if (destination[stringLength] != '\x0') {
>     destination[stringLength] = '\x0';
> }
> ```

should be:

```
destination[len] = '\0';
```

Also, `'\0'` is the standard way to write the null character.  I've never seen it written as `'\x0'` before.

## Unnecessary local variable

The variable `substringLength` is unnecessary because it is always the same as `len`.  You can just use `len` instead.

## Return value

The java substring function returns the string.  Your function returns the length but I don't think that this will be useful to the caller.  The reason you might want to return a string is so you can chain calls like this:

```
strcat(substring(buf, path, dir_start, dir_length), basename);
```

Comment: Note: `start + len > stringLength` is not safe against integer overflow.

Comment: On the other hand, if trying to emulate the [.NET Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx), then passing the length would be right.

Comment: @200_success But in the comments in the code, he specifically says he is trying to emulate the java version.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a hard time understanding how C functions are usually meant to work

The best thing to do is to read the documentation, which is only a Google search away.

For instance, you'll determine that `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, so `stringLength` should also be a `size_t`, same with `len`.  Mixing this with an `int` or other signed type can cause "possible loss of data" warnings.

Also, if you have a string called `destination`, then the other one should be called `source`.

Answer (score 1):

By first glance it looks kind of OK, but there are at least a few bugs:

- Given a `start > 0` and `len < strlen(string)`, but still large, then your `memcpy` might end up writing beyond allocated memory
- Why the `start < len` test? Given `start = 5` and `len = 2`, but `string = 'A somewhat long string'`. It should be allowed to copy 2 characters from that string. I think what you mean to check for is something like `(start + len) <= stringLength`

You should also be aware that C also have substring functions in default libraries, like `strncpy` or `strcpy`, so you're kind of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Printing an error message to stderr and returning -1 if argument validation fails isn't very good practice. For one thing, there's no way to distinguish different error cases; for another, there's no way to avoid the log spam.

If an error you detect is *always programmer error* then you should catch it with an assertion that stops the program dead in its tracks (or better yet, a static assertion that stops the program from compiling). Otherwise, if the error could be caused by user input, you should return an error code (preferably a different error code for each case) and let your caller decide how the error should be handled. Printing a canned error to the screen may not be what the user of your function wants!

Finally, you have the opportunity to decide that some cases aren't errors at all. It can be convenient, and reduce the number of special cases in calling code, to allow the boundaries of a substring to be outside of the source string, or to allow the end position to be less than the start position, and to just trim the output string apprirately, and many standard substring functions allow some or all of these combinations.

For example, you might use the substring function to get the "first 80 characters of `headline`" to display a summary, but it doesn't need to be an error if the headline is less than 80 characters to begin with; the summary in that case would just be the whole headline. You might also get the rest of the headline by asking for a substring *beginning* at character 80, for a short headline this can just be the empty string instead of returning an error. This preserves the property that headline = summary + remainder. There are tradeoffs involved in stronger and weaker validation, but my point is that if you can come up with meaningful behavior for a set of arguments, then your function might be more useful by allowing it, rather than being needlessly restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

**`char *destination` needs a size**

Any new string function can be made far more robust by passing in the size of the destination array.  The minor performance saving by not having to do size limitations is far outweighed by the grief cause by message overruns.

**Use `size_t` for all string sizes and indexes**.  Type `int` may be of insufficient range especially for this function whose goal is to make sub-strings of larger strings.

**Avoid an argument name like `string`**.  Use a name that describes its role.

```
// size_t substring(char *destination, char const *string,  int start, int len) {
size_t substring(char *destination, size_t dsize, char const *source,  
    size_t start, size_t len) {
```

**Investigate `restrict`**.  Your present code has trouble if `destination` and `string` overlap.  Either adjust code to handle that or use `restrict` to indicate your function can not cope with overlap.

**Define corner cases**

Instead of returning `(size_t)-1`, on "start and len must be 0 < start/len < length of string", define a plausible functionality.

Along with using `size_t dsize`, there should be no error conditions possible.   All possible legitimate inputs should result in a defined result.

```
// dest and source may overlap
void substring1(char *dest, size_t dsize, const char *source, size_t start, size_t length) {
  size_t source_len = strlen(source);
  if (start > source_len) start = source_len;
  if (start + length*1ull > source_len) length = source_len - start;
  if (length + 1 > dsize) {
    if (dsize == 0) {
      return;
    }
    length = dsize - 1;
  }
  memmove(dest, &source[start], length);
  dest[length] = 0;
}
```

Ref: [Sample implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29440624/2410359)

Comment: It's the caller's responsibility to provide a `destination` buffer that is long enough to contain the result. It seems silly to have to pass `dsize` just to reassure `substring1()` of that fact.

Comment: @200_success C's standard library  has grown with `size` restricted functions like `snprintf()`, `strftime()`, many others too  and has dropped the unrestricted size function like `gets()`.  The standard's direction to using `size_t` in more functions is not silly.  Since my coding style reflects that model,  checking `size` is a legitimate coding style.  We may professionally disagree on this, but neither approach is silly - the larger program's coding goals often drive the best approach.

Comment: We already have a length argument. Adding another one makes the API more cumbersome but not a bit safer.

Answer (score 0):

### Interface

Your function looks more like the [.NET Substring function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) (for which you specify the `length`) than the [Java substring function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) (for which you specify the exclusive `endIndex`).

### Validation

**Calling `strlen()`** anywhere in this function is, in my opinion, not acceptable.  If I'm trying to extract the first 5 bytes of a megabyte-long string, why should the operation require the entire string to be traversed?

**Polluting standard error** is unconventional in a library function like this: no function in the standard C library reports errors that way.  Errors should be reported by returning an error code, returning an error code via an out-parameter, or via a global error flag (which is less preferred, but still acceptable).  In this case, you could also **use assertions** instead, since out-of-bounds errors are programmer errors, not user errors.

If you want to return an error code, you should not return `-1` as a `size_t`, because **`size_t` is is unsigned**.

Alternatively, consider redefining the behaviour such that out-of-bounds access just produces an empty or shorter result, rather than an error.  (That's not how the .NET and Java functions behave, though.)  Then, you could design the function such that it returns the length of the string that was actually copied (which would ideally be the same as `len`, but might be shorter if the bounds were wrong).

### Implementation

Instead of `memcpy()`, the function you want to use is [`strncpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncpy.html):

```
strncpy(destination, string + start, len);
destination[len] = '\0';           /* Important! */
```

Or, better yet, if `stpncpy()` is available on your target platform:

```
char *termination = stpncpy(destination, string + start, len)
*termination = '\0';                /* Important! */
return termination - destination;   /* The length of the result */
```